# Maven Implementation

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

Hi I am implementing on of my ant project into maven.
I have one parent project which is creating a EAR file.
one web project and 1 service and 1 schema project.
I have shared libraries with .EAR extension.
In shared libraries we have some common dependencies which is use in all projects.
so let's say i want to build following project

```
  <groupId>Services1</groupId>
  <artifactId>Services1</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Then i need some classes from shared libraries let say Shared-util.ear.
I am trying to include 
**

```
 <groupId>iservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>ear</type>
```

**
but maven is not taking this ear as dependency. but when i extract this ear and get particular jar file from there
**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>iservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>commom-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>**
```

It is working fine.So is there any way that maven read classes from EAR.
I know it is little bit complicated question but I am trying to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

maven does not read and use dependencies from wars and ears (which may contain jars).  Your project set up is unconventional.  You could look at installing/deploying the jars which make up your ear in local/mirrored repository and then use it as a normal dependency.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestions yes that think i already done it is working fine.but i am trying different solution for trying to put as modules in my pom file still it is not working the reason i am doing this ear shared-libraries has lots of jar file and rather than breaking all jars i am trying to tell maven to read jars from EAR's but i think this is not possible let's what can i do...!! and you know how to make project dynamic like ant has build.properties file how we include property file in maven. thanks in advance